# PHP color code gone in aptana 3?

Tags: php, aptana, aptana3

I use Aptana Studio 3 for coding in PHP.
Previous I used Aptana Studio 2 where my PHP code was more colored.
In Aptana Studio 3 the code remains black and some stuff gets blue.
I have the Aptana Studio 2.x theme applied.

*Aptana Studio 3 screenshot:*

[image: Aptana studio 3]

How can I get it to color more parts of my code like in Aptana Studio 2 ?

*Aptana Studio 2 screenshot:*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have tested this on my copy of Aptana Studio 3 for OS X, and I get exaclty the same results. I've tested several other themes as well. They all colorize the syntax in the correct way, *except* the 'Aptana 2.x' theme. So this seems to be a fault with that specific theme.

You could copy the Aptana 2 default theme, and import it into Aptana 3, but there's no guarantee it will work in the same way.

What I can recommend is that you use the included 'Eclipse' theme, since that offers the correct syntax-highlighting. It's also similar to what you're used to.

Comment: The PHP gets colored good with the eclipse theme but the html is not colored at all. The eclipse theme comes in handy with PHP classes tough. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i also have load another syntax-highlight-style, cause i love dark themes. And the default-syntax-highligting was unusable with dark background.

You mayy find this or other for dark-themes (http://www.thelogfile.com/blog/2009/05/29/eclipse-syntax-highlighting-theme/)

But be sure to check "Enable Invasive Themes" Checkbox on Pereferences > Aptana Studio > Themes

Comment: Well I tried the theme your link pointed out but it was highly unusable, black font on black background in some cases. It took me a while to get it back to normal but thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

That was not the style, i'm using. I'm only search in google for syntax-highlight aptana.
I have another one, but didn't remember where i got it.
But wait, i will have a look.....

K, found it.
My is named: eclipse_theme-rogerdudler_com.epf And i realy like it.
Maybe search for it in google.